# AngularJS, change model value with checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I have a bound data variable named 'bool' which has a value of 100. When I click a checkbox I'd like the value to increase by adding 50 to it. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <h3 ng-model="bool = 100">BOOL</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="add = 50"/>
    <div>{{bool + add}}</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you :)

Comment: Don't you have a Controller for this app? Can you show us your Javascript code - your controller?

Comment: I do have an empty controller, I was wondering if this was possible purely through directive computation, don't need the data to go anywhere

Comment: I'd suggest you try using the Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-model` cannot be an expression. If you need to assign a default value you should use `ng-init`.

Also, a checkbox has a value of either true (1) or false (0). So although `{{bool + add}}` will initially display `150`, as soon as you check or uncheck the checkbox it will display either `100` or `101` because now `add` is either 0 or 1 depending on the checked state.

```js
angular.module('app', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="app">
      <h3 ng-model="bool" ng-init="bool = 100; additional = 0">BOOL</h3>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="add" ng-change="additional = add * 50"/>
        <div>{{bool + additional}}</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Lex, yep I tried that. What it does is initialize the value to 150, then on checkbox click sets it 101 (true having a value of 1) and on toggle switches between 100 and 101.

Comment: What I need is for the initial value to be 100 and on checkbox click, the value toggles to 150

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this in the HTML, but I have updated my answer to show one possible approach. As suggested by ishmaelMakitla, though, this type of logic really belongs in the controller.